# Read data from Redis from different applications

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We are using a serviceA to extract data from a database and putting it into redis(We are using Spring data/Jedis with the method saveAll).

There is another serviceB that needs to get all the objects from the same redis instance.

The structure of the object from the serviceA is exactly the same of the serviceB. We are having problems because the serviceA is doing his job fine, but the service B extract all the data with the method findAll() provided from Spring data but they are all null values.

Note: We made a test loading all the data from the serviceB, so we got all the objects without any problem. The only difference That I can see from both hashes on redis is the field _class that autogenerates when we are loading the data from serviceA.

Can you please give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are consistent on how keys are serialized between `serviceA` and `serviceB`. To me, it sounds like `serviceA` is writing data for a given serialized key and then `serviceB` tries to fetch the data for a different serialized key. If, for example, you are using Jackson in both 'serviceA' and 'serviceB', make sure it is configured in the same way.

Redis is essentially a distributed `Map<String, String>`, so if there is a difference in how `serviceA` serializes data and how `serviceB` serializes data (for example, one of them storing the classname in the serialized object while the other not storing it), you will end up with different `String` keys for the same Java key object (and the service reading the data will get null as a response to `findAll` since nothing is stored in Redis at the key that it is requesting).